# matched column of a dataframe will return the value of a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Python.
I have two data frames

df1:

```
     email                    timezone       country_app_web
0   nhvfstdfg@vxc.com        Europe/Paris       NaN
1   taifoor096@gmail.com     NaN                FR
2   nivo1996@gmail.com       US/Eastern         NaN
3   jorgehersan90@gmail.com  NaN                UK
4   syeager2@cox.net         NaN                NaN
```

df2:

```
         email                          country
0   008023@abpat.qld.edu.au               AU
1   0081634947@fanaticsgsiorder.com       AU
2   008farhan05@gmail.com                 ID
3   00bronzy@gmail.com                    AU
4   00monstar@gmail.com                   AU
```

I want to check using python and add column country in df1

Problem1: if email in df1 is present in df2, if yes then return the value of a column "country" present in df2 to matched email in df1

problem 2: for the remaning unmatched emails , need to check if the country_web_app in df1 has any value corresponding to the unmatched email if yes then return the country__web_app values into country column of df1

problem 3: Similarly for remaning unmatched email after problem 2, need to check if the timezone in df1 has any value corresponding to the unamtched email if yes then return the timezone value into country column of df1

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(list(df1))):
    if df1["email"][i] == df2["email"][i]:
        df1["new_col"][i] = df2["country"][i]
```

Please mention problems 2 and 3 correctly!

Comment: problem 2: for the remaning unmatched emails , need to check if the country_web_app in df1 has any value corresponding to the unmatched email if yes then return the country__web_app  values into country column of df1

Comment: problem 3: Similarly for remaning unmatched email after problem 2, need to check if the timezone in df1 has any value corresponding to the unamtched email if yes then return the timezone value into country column of df1

Comment: Although ok, this version has serious performance limitations for large datasets.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Added more details in my answer. Also would like to add that this answer would only apply in very specific cases in which the data at the positions match (see loop). In order to make it work, a second loop would be necessary (loop on df1 for email and then loop on df2 for email).

Answer (score 0):

```py
df1.where(df1.values==df2.values).notna()
```

This would return the common entities within both data frames as boolean `True` , further this would also return the column of common entries within both data frames so achieving your tasks is easier. You may use the [`pd.dataframes.replace()`](https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-replace/) method for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map "rule" which country corresponds to which email from `df2`:

`rule = dict(zip(df2["email"], df2["country"]))`

Apply the rule into `df1`:

`df1["country"] = df1["email"].map(rule)`

BTW: this will fill not matched emails with `NaN`
The rest is relatively similar.

**EDIT** On request to a comment of mine to another answer, some timing considerations which are relevant in general and are dramatic on large datasets (on a laptop core i5 16GB, more details not really necessary):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('asd') * 1_000_000, 'b': [1,2,3] * 1_000_000})
df['new_col'] = np.nan

def remap_with_loop():
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df['new_col'][i] = df['b'][i]  # simple assignment, not even checking any condition

def remap_with_map():
    df['new_col'] = df['a'].map(dict(zip(df['a'], df['b'])))
```

The functions were built to do equivalent results, but the point is to test the performance difference of the `loop` vs `map`:

```
%timeit remap_with_loop()
1min 16s ± 2.91 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit remap_with_map()
1.03 s ± 134 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

About 76x better performance for `remap_with_map`.

The take home message is to avoid looping at all costs on dataframes or series when possible. Use pandas/numpy functions to achieve the same results. This might not always be possible, but it is in the context of this question.

Also, the version with `map` is generic and will adapt to modifying input.